# how to combine many excel tabs in one tab and create a new column with the name of every tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have excel sheet that have many tabs with different names with the same columns, I need to merge all those tabs in one df and create a new column "Queue" to declare every value to it's queue.

The problem here that I can't do this actions in all tabs at once

The Original sheet
[image]

The expected sheet
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work although you will need to fix the workbook location.

This adds the sheet name to the DataFrames within the dict and then concats the DataFrames into one.

```
import pandas as pd

workbook_location = 'Book1.xlsx'
sheets = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']
# sheets = ['ALMB-After Sales', 'ALMB-Corp', 'ALMB-Sales', 'CS', 'ALMB-OGOV', 'Flights', 'Retail', 'Sales']

inbound_new_calls = pd.read_excel(workbook_location, sheet_name = sheets)

for sheet, values in  inbound_new_calls.items():
    values['Queue'] = sheet

pd.concat(inbound_new_calls).groupby(['Queue', 'Date'])['Offered'].sum()
```